# Why won't the timer run when the audio runs?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am making a timed beep test as a skit for an event with my cadet corps and I can't get the timer to run at the same time as the beep test audio.

```
import os, playsound, multiprocessing, time

cwd = os.getcwd()
def beep_test():
    audio= "".join((cwd+"\\BTsound.mp3"))
    playsound.playsound(audio,True)

def multitasking():
        sound_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=beep_test())
        sound_process.start()

        timer = 10

        while timer > 0 and sound_process.is_alive(): 
            time.sleep(1) 
            print(f"..{timer}") 
            timer -= 1

        if timer == 0: 
            sound_process.terminate()
            print("Time's up, runners must grab a water bottle and walk around. Do not sit down.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message= input("Type 'begin beep test' to launch the timed beep test.\n")
    if "begin beep test" in message:

                        multitasking()
```

Specifics:
I use playsound 1.2.2, because 1.3.0 is bugged
It's designed to be used with a speech recognition feature, but for simplicity's sake, I replaced it with input()
On prod, the timer will be set at 600s, but for efficiency's sake, I changed it to 10 during testing

I haven't tried much, but I did move around the 'if **name** == "**main**":' hoping that it would play both the sound and timer, but to no avail.

I have troubleshot the timer, and it works alone

I've removed the 'if "begin beep test" in message:' and played the process alone, it works.

The problem seems to be in the first if, which I depend on to activate it, as I have other functionalities on the main program (I.E music).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target argument needs to take a function name, not call the function.

What's happening at the minute is that you are calling beep_test yourself, rather than letting the other process handle it.

Change it to `multiprocessing.Process(target=beep_test)`.